# Loading Mnist data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load MNIST data in tensor flow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

Error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

I am brand new to TF, so any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Were you connected to internet when running the code?

Comment: @MatějRačinský Yes I was.

Answer (score 1):

TimeoutResponseError when downloading data are usually caused by common Network issues,
such as:
1. Proxy Setup,
2. Firewall,
3. Company restrictions,
You should investigate on these, because this type of Error can be caused by multiple things